# How to choose an image that will remain even after exiting the app

Tags: swift, xcode

I need help please I have a button .. and UIImage without a picture for the user can choose a picture he wants!
And it's important that the user-selected image stays the same once the user is completely signed out of the app

I want the user to select a picture from the gallery or take a picture and then the picture he chose will be displayed on the profile picture and will not disappear even after exiting the application .. The data will be saved
Can I do this please?

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var chooseBuuton: UIButton!
    var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()




    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: NSDictionary!){
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in

        })

        imageView.image = image
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    }
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

        let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
        imageView.image = image
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill



        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        let controller = UIImagePickerController()
        controller.delegate = self
        controller.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to save it in local database to keep it even after app exits.

Comment: Use, `UserDefault` for easy, `DB(Core Data)` for Perfect and `Local image save (as the file)` in the directory for the small amount of size.

Comment: Standard practice here would be to store the file in the applications documents directory and save a reference to it somewhere. you could save the filename in user defaults or core data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save image in Application storage like [UserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults), [Document directory](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html) or in DB if you are using in Application.

Preferably images are saving to Application document directory, you can use below method to save image:

```
func saveImage(image : UIImage, imageName: String){
        let documentDirectoryPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

        let fileURL = documentDirectoryPath.appendingPathComponent(imageName)
        if let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0),
            !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path) {
            do {
                try data.write(to: fileURL)
                print("Image saved")
            } catch {
                print("Image save error:", error)
            }
        }
    }
```

You can get back image via below function:

```
func getImage(imageName: String) -> UIImage?{
        let documentDirectoryPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let fileURL = documentDirectoryPath.appendingPathComponent(imageName)
        let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: fileURL.path)
        return image
    }
```

In your `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` delegate method call function `saveImage` with image & imageName to save image in document directory permanently:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    // Do your stuff here, then save image to document directory:
     saveImage(image:image, imageName: "profile.jpg")
    }
```

To show image on your imageView get image from document directory in your `viewDidLoad` function:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        if let image = getImage(imageName: "profile.jpg"){
            imageview.image = image
        }
    }
```

Comment: *Thank you for your experience and help
But it could not leave the selected photo from the album as soon as you're completely out of the app(I do not want to save an image into a photo album
)*

Comment: @testerbeta - I couldn't getting your point, can you explain what is your requirement?

Comment: *I have a button .. and UIImage without a picture for the user can choose a picture he wants!
And it's important that the user-selected image stays the same once the user is completely signed out of the app*

Comment: Yes, for it you have to save image in document directory permanently & when you returning back to your App after quit then need to get image from document directory. the above two function completely fulfil your requirement.

Comment: *I think you did not understand me bro
I just want the user selects an image from his gallery from the phone .and needs the image to stay on a regular UIImage*

Comment: *I do not want to save a picture into the gallery of the phone ...
Only the image that is used as a profile photo will still remain after you completely exit the app*

Comment: @testerbeta- it'll not save the image into gallery, it save into application's document directory, Just follow the step mentioned above, you'll get your desired result.

Comment: *I try and I can not
Can you edit it for me please?*

Comment: *I succeeded. Thank you very much*

Comment: *how Allow the user to choose the profile picture he wants and change whenever he wants
*