# Allow the user to choose the profile picture he wants and change whenever he wants

Tags: swift, xcode

I need help please i try to do  UIImage without a picture for the user can choose a picture he wants! And it's important that the user-selected image holds the same once the user is completely signed out of the app
And he can change it whenever he wants to see what picture he wants
displayed on the profile picture (UIImage)
Swift 4

```
        class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var chooseBuuton: UIButton!
    var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()




    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: NSDictionary!){
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in

        })

        imageView.image = image
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    }
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

        let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
        imageView.image = image
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill



        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        let controller = UIImagePickerController()
        controller.delegate = self
        controller.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not Understood you Question. You mean to say when you pick a image from image picker, it should be displayed in there, and should be there also if you close the app and open again.? If user log out, It should be removed.?

Comment: * the user can choose a picture he wants!  And he can change it whenever he wants to see what picture he wants displayed on the profile picture (UIImage*

Comment: You can see the answer i posted for you use case. Hope so it helps You.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me It does not work for me .. maybe i'm not doing it right ... can you please edit it along with my code please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to choose an image that will remain even after exiting the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49688170/how-to-choose-an-image-that-will-remain-even-after-exiting-the-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i am not Wrong You want the Image to be Stored in As it if also the User sign out from app.

You can possibly Store the Image in **Document Directory**

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        let path = try! FileManager.default.url(for: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, in: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
        let newPath = path.appendingPathComponent("image.jpg") //Possibly you can Use the UserName to fetch easily User-wise
        let jpgImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)
        do {
            try jpgImageData!.write(to: newPath)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

**To Fetch the Image Back:-**

```
let nsDocumentDirectory = FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory
let nsUserDomainMask    = FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask
let paths               = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(nsDocumentDirectory, nsUserDomainMask, true)
if let dirPath          = paths.first
    {
        let imageURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: dirPath).appendingPathComponent("image.png")
        let image    = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageURL.path)
        // Do whatever you want with the image
}
```

Hope this Helps you.

You can use Scenario Like. Initially The image view will be Empty.

1. User will select the image using picker View.
2. It will be stored in Document Directory
3. User Log out from App
4. User log in back to app(At that time check if any image is there with the users name then fetch from Document directory and directly
   show or else blank)
5. User can change profile picture and step 1-4 Repeated

**Edited :**  Integrated in you Code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var chooseBuuton: UIButton!
var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()


override func viewDidLoad() {

    //Check if image exist in Document Directory

    let nsDocumentDirectory = FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory
    let nsUserDomainMask    = FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask
    let paths               = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(nsDocumentDirectory, nsUserDomainMask, true)
    if let dirPath          = paths.first
    {
        let imageURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: dirPath).appendingPathComponent("image.png")
        let image    = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageURL.path)
        imageView.image = image
    }else{

        // Image not present
        // Do whatever you want to do here
    }
}


func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: NSDictionary!){
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in

    })

    imageView.image = image
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        imageView.image = image
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        let path = try! FileManager.default.url(for: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, in: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
        let newPath = path.appendingPathComponent("image.jpg") //Possibly you can Use the UserName to fetch easily User-wise
        let jpgImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)
        do {
            try jpgImageData!.write(to: newPath)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    let controller = UIImagePickerController()
    controller.delegate = self
    controller.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
}}
```

Possibly This would help You. Let me know if it works

Comment: *Thank you for trying to help me
It does not work for me .. maybe i'm not doing it right ... can you please edit it along with my code please*

Comment: @testerbeta I have Edited the Code, I have tried using it in your code. Hope so it helps.

Comment: @testerbeta It was my pleasure helping You.